# SQl: Case within Count while Group By

Tags: sql

I have a system that requires user to fill out a number of charts. They can fill out as many as they desire but they must at least fill out 2. I need to build a SQL calls that counts how many forms have been filled out but should only count a max of 2 per person.

Everything is working as expected except for the `Count()` function.

```
Select mappingid, formTypeId as "Form Type", abbreviation, 
   Count( case when formtypeid >= 2 then 2 else formTypeID end) as "Chart Count"
        From tables.dbo.forms
        where questions = answered and formtypeid = 3
        group by mappingid, formtypeid, abbreviation;
```

Line 7, the last column should print out 2 as opposed to 4.

[image]

**Edit - Data added**

[image]

Comment: please post sample data from the table as well

Comment: @Regis , correct me if im wrong ..but i think not only row 7 , because your operator is greater than or equal (>=) , meaning , row 1,2,4,5 and 7 will become 2.

Comment: If you want only row 7 , you need only greater than (>2) not (>=2)

Comment: If it's >= 2 then it would out print 2 anyway. So yes, either would work (theoretically).

Comment: @Regis , i see .. then hope my answer below will work on you :)

Comment: `I need to build a SQL calls that counts how many forms have been filled out but doesn't count the ones where users filled out more than 2` It will not count the ones where users filled out more than 2 then what should be displayed instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
Select mappingid, formTypeId as "Form Type", abbreviation,
case when count(formtypeid) >= 2 then 2 else Count(formTypeID) end as "Chart Count"
From tables.dbo.forms
where questions = answered and formtypeid = 3
group by mappingid, formtypeid, abbreviation;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this changes everything in the third column to 2.

Comment: @Regis , really ? 3rd column ? , but i change the logic only in 4th column to make your `COUNT` function works.

Comment: @Regis , i see .. column 2 is your formtypetid , answer above already modified , see if it works.. i misunderstood your question, next time include the column name on your screen shot :) my apologies .. i modified my answer.

Comment: Sorry, fourth column. I had to move one of the brackets in your post because of a syntax error, other than that it works. Thank you!

Comment: @approxiblue , thank you for correcting wrong place of closing bracket :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want to limit the count to a maximum of 2:

```
Select mappingid, formTypeId as FormType, abbreviation, 
       (case when count(*) > 2 then 2 else count(*) end) as ChartCount
From tables.dbo.forms
where questions = answered and formtypeid = 3
group by mappingid, formtypeid, abbreviation;
```